# beignet-opencl-icd not available in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: plex, opencl, hevc

I just installed a Plex Media Server on my Ubuntu 22.04 server. According to Plex's website: https://support.plex.tv/articles/hdr-to-sdr-tone-mapping/, beignet-opencl-icd is required for hardware transcoding with HDR to SDR Tone Mapping. However, beignet-opencl-icd is unavailable in the Ubuntu 22.04 repository.

Comment: Same problem here.
Found something on Plex Forum and it seems that they are working on this problem. https://forums.plex.tv/t/ubuntu-22-04-remove-beignet-opencl-icd/790473